# Howto create threadsave a file without overwriting an existent one?

Tags: delphi, thread-safety

until now, whenever I wanted to create a file without overwriting an existing one, I've done something like this:

```
if not FileExists(filename) then
  stream := TFileStream.Create(filename, fmCreate);
```

But that's not threadsafe. So now I am looking for a threadsafe version.

Perhaps I can combine some modes so that `TFileStream.Create(filename, fmCreate +fm???);` fails if the file exists?

I need this to communicate directory-locks with old DOS programs. But the DOS programs don't hold the files opened. :-(

Comment: Do the DOS programs have to lock the file also? Making the Delphi application thread-safe won't make DOS programs thread-safe. And we are not speaking about threads, but about processes here. Are you sure you are dealing with DOS programs, not Win32 command-line programs? In order to be sure that we give you a working solution, we'll need to know more about the "DOS programs" part of your architecture: how do they work? which app is locking the directory? which kind of state-machine are you using for the locking?

Comment: what is this DOS of which you speak? Are you running on windows 98?

Comment: @David, AFAIK you can run DOS programs on all 32 bit versions of Windows, including Windows 7 32 bit; No need for Windows 98!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TFileStream`'s file-name based constructor relies on the WIndows API call [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858.aspx) to create the file handle that'll be used to access the file. The API itself has multiple parameters, and especially interesting for you is the *Create Disposition*: if you specify `CREATE_NEW`, the function fails if the file already exists. You can take advantage of that by calling `CreateFile` yourself, then using the returned handle to create the `TFileStream`. You can do that because `TFileStream` inherits from `THandleStream`, inherits it's handle-based constructor and owns the handle (calls `CloseHandle` on the handle you pass to the constructor).

Since this relies on the OS-provided function `CreateFile`, it'll be trehad-safe (no race condition between `FileExists()` and actually creating the file. It also blocks the old application from accessing the newly crearted file until you actually close the handle.

```
var FH: NativeUInt;

// ...

  FH := CreateFile('FileName', GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE, 0, nil, CREATE_NEW, 0, 0);
  if FH = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  begin
    // Creating the new file failed! I'm raizing an exception, but you can do something
    // better-suited for your case, like trying a new file name.
    RaiseLastOSError;
  end;
  // Create the stream using the prepared Handle
  HS := TFileStram.Create(FH);
```

Comment: This is the more elegant solution, for implementing a cross-process file creation. But I found out the question to be confusing: what are those "DOS programs" about? How does the locking work? Your solution won't work with DOS programs, but only with Win32 Delphi programs.

Comment: @A.Bouchez, I'd expect the solution to also work with DOS programs, since it'd happen at OS level; Unfortunately I no longer have any trace of a DOS program to test with!

Comment: @Cosmin The CreateFile API is a Win32 API, not a DOS API. If the DOS programs just expect the *locking file* to be present on disk and created by Delphi, then release the lock by deleting the file, it will work. But if the DOS program also need to lock the file, it won't work if it does not follow the same scheme as your CreateFile call. That's why I asked for more details about those "DOS programs"...

Comment: @A.Bouchez, if the DOS program can't create the file, the program try try it again later.

Comment: @A.Bouchez, the CreateFile API is an OS provided service, the DOS application (if it's truly DOS) would access the same service through the int 21h vector. The key here is, the same service, implemented by the same operating system. About the lock file expected by the DOS application, I don't think that's an issue: DOS was a single-user, single-process and single-threaded operating system. Applications weren't designed with concurrency in mind, so I doubt the DOS application would check for LOCKS. It might check for "job complete", ie, check if the file it's about to generate exists.

Answer (score 4):

I would keep the `FileExists` check because it handles most cases without relying on exception handling. For the border cases you have to handle exceptions in `TFileStream` constructor properly. The second thread trying to create the file should fail if you use it with share mode `fmShareDenyWrite`.